# Proof of Power Rule for Limits using epsilon-delta

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

The power rule for limits is,

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left[f(x)^n\right]=L^n$

It seems that the typical approach to proving this rule is by using induction in combination with the product law for limits. But is there a way to prove the power rule using the epsilon-delta style of proofing? I can't find a single resources online that discusses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, then there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ then $|f(x)-L| <1$, and hence $|f(x)|<1+|L|$ (the point here is that if a function has a limit, then it is bounded in some small interval around that point).

Now, let $\epsilon>0$, and choose $\delta_2>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta_2$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Define $\delta:= \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$; I claim this works. So, suppose $0<|x-a|<\delta$ now. Then,
\begin{align}
|f(x)^n-L^n|&=\left|[f(x)-L]\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x)^{n-k}L^{k-1}\right|\\
&\leq |f(x)-l|\sum_{k=1}^n|f(x)|^{n-k}L^{k-1}\\
&\leq \epsilon \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n (1+|L|)^{n-k}L^{k-1}
\end{align}
Now, that big ugly summation term, let's call it $M$. Whatever it is, it doesn't matter; it is just some finite positive number depending only on $L$ (the key point is it doesn't depend on $\epsilon$).

Thus, what we have shown is that there exists an $M\geq 0$ (namely $M=\sum_{k=1}^n(1+|L|)^{n-k}L^{k-1}$) such that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)^n-L^n|\leq M\epsilon$. This is entirely equivalent to proving $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)^n=L^n$.

If you have the "desire" to finish off proofs with an $\epsilon$ in the end, then I invite you to reword this proof to make that happen.

---

The idea of the proof is to use the familiar formula to factor $f(x)^n-L^n$ as a product of $f(x)-L$ and some function which is bounded. Since $|f(x)-L|$ can be made small, if you multiply by something bounded (i.e you have control over how big it is), the result is still "small" (in the grand scheme of things). Hence, $|f(x)^n-L^n|$ is also small. In other words, the crux of this proof is that
\begin{align}
\text{small}\cdot \text{bounded} =\text{small}.
\end{align}

Comment: This was a very detailed and astonishing well explained response. I was expecting a hint or two lol. Thank you so much. I know comments aren't for gratitude statements but you deserve it.